# Why isn't Google Analytics Goal Tracking working?

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

I want to use Google Analytics to track registrations on my site. I don't see anything in my Google Analytics reports. Here is my markup:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register"  onSubmit="pageTracker._trackEvent('Goals','Registration');"/>
```

I'd like to know how to make this work, or how to troubleshot what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics has Goal Tracking and Event Tracking.  I believe you are using event tracking.

- All about event tracking:
  http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html
- All about goals and funnels: http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55515

Let me know if that isn't your issue.  These two tracking systems in Google Analytics can be somewhat confusing.

Comment: I think you are correct Random that I'm confused between the two. I think I want Goals so I can use Goal Flow and Goal URL's.

Comment: @DavidSilvaSmith I thought so.  At firs the 2 would appear to be the same and Google language sometimes doesn't help the situation.  I have found events are most useful for things like tracking clicks on outbound links where there is no funnel.